# DDD - Partial source file

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, ddd-debugger

I am using DDD to debug a program with many files and I am able to successfully set breakpoints and step through C source code.  Sometimes, with larger source files, I find that when I try to step into a function that is located near the end of the file (e.g. beyond line 1200 or so), the entire source file is not displayed in the debugger.  In other words, only the first 1200 or so lines of the source files are displayed, and even though I am stepping through code in the last half of the file, I can't see it.  Why is the source file being clipped, and what can I do to get DDD to load the entire file, not just the first part of it?

Answer (score 3):

ddd seems to have problems with characters above ASCII 127 in the source code. Here ddd stoped working at a location where the text "m²" was written into a C comment. The ² was contained in a text with ISO 8859-15 encoding (ASCII 178). Deleting that character solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

`LANG=C ddd ...`

or

`export LANG=C
ddd ...`